# Tensorflow maxpooling in conv2d filter instead of atrous_conv2d

Tags: computer-vision, tensorflow

I want to perform a convolution on a big patch of the image. But I don't want too have to many variables, one solution could be to use the `atrous_conv2d` function but I would prefer apply first a `max_pool` on the patch, then the regular `conv2d`. How can I do this?

I have to keep the same image size between input and output. Here the code with the `atrous_conv2d` function

```
x = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, size_x*size_y])
image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,size_x , size_y,1])

W = weight_variable([9, 9, 1, n])

conv =tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(image, W,  10, padding='SAME')
```

If I understand correctly the patch size of the `atrous_conv2d` convolution is (9*10 X 9*10) but it act on each different pixel at 10 pixel interval and need only 9X9Xn variables.

I would prefer to take the same patch size, apply a `max_pool` on it, then a conventional `conv2d` on the (9X9) patch resulting from the `max_pool`. At the end it would produce the same numbers of variables but it could provide smoother results. The code could look like this :

```
x = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, size_x*size_y])
image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,size_x , size_y,1])

W = weight_variable([9, 9, 1, n])

def maxp(patch):
  tf.sum_reduce(tf.nn.max_pool(patch, ksize=[1,10,10,1],
                               strides=[1,10,10,1], padding='SAME')*W)

conv=conv_func(image,maxp,patch_size=[1,9*10,9*10,1],strides=[1,1,1,1])
```

where `conv_func` take as argument the value, a function and a patch_size and apply the function on the patch.

Comment: You can maybe first downsample with a max pooling, and then upsample to the initial size with [`tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d_transpose) ?

Comment: Hum... that seems a good idea, I am not sure it produce the result that I want but I will try. Thanks!

Comment: You may add more details to your problem (input, output...) if you want a more precise answer !